# WPML Advanced Translation Editor kills code modules in DIVI

Tags: wpml, divi

**Environment**:

- DIVI: 4.10.7
- WPML Multilingual CMS 4.4.12
- WPML String Translation 3.1.10
- Wordpress: 5.8.1

We use WPML to translate our pages from standard language (english) to 4 other languages (french, spanish, russian and german)

Problem pages:
... contain code modules with JavaScript and Form code.

How to reproduce the problem:

1. Delete Permanently a translated page
2. Add again the translation page by hitting "+" Sign to add a language version of a given page
3. Translate all strings using ATE (Advanced Translation Editor)

The problem is in step 3 is that WPML does not perfectly recognize JavaScript code. Thus it offers part of the code to translate.

[image]

So in order to get a 100% translated page I need to also translate those (without changing the text of course).

**Result:**
The resulting page gets garbled as form and code modules of the translated page only contains part of the necessary code.

[image]

**Questions:**

- Has anyone achieved using current WPML and DIVI along with code modules containing JavaScript and/or `<form>` code.
- Is there a workaround to mark code modules in a way so they are not touched by WPML?
- I suppose that the translation memory for the problem pages somehow interferes. Why? Because I recognize different behaviour. While adding a german page normally works ok I get problems more often with Russian version. So perhaps it's a caching problem of WPML? (And yes I cleared the browser cache)

**What I already tried / researched**

- I am in contact with WPML support.  If I get a solution there I will post it here
- It seems other users have similar problems: https://wpml.org/forums/topic/divi-code-module-code-visible-on-translated-pages/ Although translating the page twice does work for me.
- https://wpml.org/forums/topic/the-translator-breaks-the-code-in-divi-code-modules/ (it describes the same problem but without giving a solution, just makes me think i am not alone :-))

Answer (score 0):

It seems that upgrading to 4.5 and using this workaround seems to work: https://wpml.org/errata/wpml-4-5-divi-text-align-rule-not-applied-to-translation/